# find the number of permutations of $(1,2,\ldots, n)$ with exactly $k$ discordant pairs.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math, recurrence-relations

> Let $(x_1,\cdots, x_n)$ be a permutation of $(1,\cdots, n)$. Call the pair $(x_i, x_j)$ discordant if $i < j$ and $x_i > x_j$. Let $d(n,k)$ be the number of permutations of $(1,2,\cdots, n)$ with exactly $k$ discordant pairs. Find $d(n,2)$ and $d(n,3)$.

The problem might be similar to the number of permutations with $k$ descents, denoted $A(n,k).$ This relation has the recurrence $A(n + 1,k + 1) = (2+k)A(n,k+1) + (n-k)A(n,k).$
I'm not sure if there's a similar recurrence relation for $d(n,k)$. Trying some small values like $n=3, k = 1$ gives $(1,3,2), (2,3,1)$ as the only valid permutations.

> Edit: a more useful approach is to use the generating function for the number of inversions. But that requires computing the coefficient of $[x^i]$ of $\prod_{j=1}^n (1+x+\cdots + x^{j-1})$ for $i=2,3$ (corresponding to $d(n,2)$ and $d(n,3)$. The formula for the generating series is justified [here](https://academic.csuohio.edu/bmargolius/homepage/inversions/invers.htm#:%7E:text=Let%20In(k)%20represent,length%20n%20with%20k%20inversions.&text=Clearly%2C%20the%20number%20of%20permutations,is%20correct%20for%20n%20%3D%201). For the coefficient of $x^2,$ I believe it should be ${n-1\choose 2} + (n-2)$ (there are $n-2$ ways to choose $x^2$, corresponding to the indices $j=3$ to $j=n$ and ${n-1\choose 2}$ ways to choose two x's corresponding to indices from $2$ to $n$). For the coefficient of $x^3,$ using similar reasoning we get $(n-3) + 2{n-2\choose 2} + {n-1\choose 3}.$

Comment: In combinatorics, these are called "inversions"; see https://oeis.org/A008302 for some sources relating to the sequence $d(n,k)$.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my post.

Comment: "$(1, 3, 2), (2, 3, 1)$"  Perhaps not.

Comment: An independent way to verify these answers would be to argue why a permutation with very few inversions can only have a finite number of arrangements, separated by fixed points.  For example, the permutations with one inversion have a single pair $(i + 1, i)$ out of order and all other points fixed; the permutations with two inversions have either two disjoint pairs $(i + 1, i)$ and $(j + 1, j)$ out of order, or have a contiguous triple in one of the arrangements $(j + 2, j, j + 1)$ or $(j + 1, j + 2, j)$.  (For three inversions, there are a few more cases.)

Comment: Also the generating function *is* equivalent to a recurrence -- it involves more terms by simpler coefficients: $d(n, k) = d(n - 1, k) + d(n - 1, k - 1) + \ldots + d(n - 1, k - n + 1)$.  One arrives at the recurrence from the same argument that leads to the generating function.